# UpdatePanel updating contents in other update panel while fileupload

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, updatepanel

I have two update panels,both have update mode as conditional, one update panel has textbox,dropdown,checbox etc., other update panel has file upload that postback on file upload.
My issue is that when i upload file all contents in first update panel also becomes empty or default, but i want contents to be kept as it was set by user before updating.

```
`<asp:UpdatePanel updatemode="conditional"..
 <Content.. 
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Width="350px" Height="19px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddParent" DataSourceID="LDSParent">       
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:LinqDataSource runat="server" ID="LDS" OnSelecting="LDS_Selecting">
</asp:LinqDataSource>
</Content..
</asp:UpdatePanel 
<asp:UpdatePanel updatemode="conditional"..
 <Content.. 
<asp:fileupload..
</Content..
</asp:UpdatePanel..`  

protected void LDS_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
    {  

        e.Result = (from p in table_name
                    select p);

    }
```

Comment: Show code where you initializing state of controls in 1st UpdatePanel

Comment: edited..state is just retrieves data from db

Comment: Does data retrieved from DB by a magic, or you still have some code for such purpose? If so, show that code.

Comment: With posted code, all I can to suggest it's to bind controls in 1st UpdatePanel only on initial request. If you have `Bind` methods calls in `Page_Load` method, put them in `if(!IsPostback){}` block

Answer (score 0):

FileUpload control will not work with UpdatePanel as it required full postback. You can not call file upload control asynchronously.